# Swift 3: Convert PromiseKit deferred to RxSwift

Tags: swift3, reactive-programming, deferred, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I'm currently replacing PromiseKit with RxSwift, and need to convert my deferred promise to RxSwift.

Current implementation example in PromiseKit:

```
private var deferredDidLayout = Promise<()>.pending()

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.deferredDidLayout.fulfill()
}

func setup() {
    _ = self.didLayout().then {_ -> Void in
        // Do my stuff only one time!
    }
}

private func didLayout() -> Promise<()> {
    return self.deferredDidLayout.promise
}
```

Current hack-implementation in RxSwift:

```
private let observableDidLayout = PublishSubject<Void>()

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    self.observableDidLayout.onCompleted()
}

func setup() {
     _ = self.observableDidLayout
        .subscribe(onCompleted: { _ in
            // Do my stuff only one time!
            // Issue: Will be executed on every onCompleted() call
     })
}
```

Thank you in regard!

PromiseKit: https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit
RxSwift: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that 'Completable' is what you are looking for - https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/Documentation/Traits.md#creating-a-completable

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
'Completable' could be part of the solution. But it does not satisfied my entire problem: 
- When the first subscriber subscribes to 'cacheLocally()' from your link the 'Completable' emits an error or an completed state.
- When the second subscriber subscribes to 'cacheLocally()' the state above (error or completed) should be saved, meaning 'cacheLocally()' should only be executed one time, and afterwards just execute the second subscribers onCompleted/onError methods directly?
In that way 'cacheLocally()' shouldn't create a new 'Completable', but reuse the same.

Comment: In my original question the implementation in PromiseKit fulfil my deferredDidLayout promise once. And if a second function used ( _ = self.didLayout().then {} ) after the deferredDidLayout promise was fulfilled, the code inside {} in second function would be executed directly.

Comment: @PAK there are plenty of possibilities to buffer/replay the last state in Rx. Possibly, something like '.asObservable().materialize().shareReplay(1)' will do, or some other '.share()/.replay()' operators. Or maybe 'ReplaySubject' will suit better.  Or 'BehaviorSubject'. There are really many ways of doing it, depends on your particular case.

Comment: shareReplay(1) was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!